# $.ajax Phonegap apk build now not working

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, post, phonegap

I am using latest PhoneGap version, and doing ajax calls.

```
function setting_main() {
        var smsid = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
        var model = device.model;
        var uui = device.uuid;
        var platform = device.platform;

        var url_webservice = 'http://mywebsite.com/webservice/db.php';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url_webservice,
            data: 'act=check_device&model=' + model+'&uui='+uui+'&platform='+platform+'&smsid='+smsid,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                localStorage.setItem("unit", res.unit);
                localStorage.setItem("id_device", res.id);
                localStorage.setItem("login_before", res.login_before);
                localStorage.setItem("user_id", res.user_id);
                localStorage.setItem("user_key", res.user_id);
                localStorage.setItem("user_type", res.user_type);
                localStorage.setItem("user_key_parent", res.user_key_parent);
                if(res.login_before==0){
                    window.location.replace('login.html');
                }else{
                    if(res.user_type!=1) {
                        window.location.replace('groups.html');
                    }else{
                        window.location.replace('groups_teacher.html');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', setting_main, false);
```

Before, this code works, but this week, When I test my app on desktop browser or mobile PhoneGap Developer App, it works fine, but after building application (.apk), ajax requests do not work and fall on failure rather than success. I have done all the configurations mentioned which include:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="~1.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" spec="~6.0.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="~2.1.3" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="~1.8.0">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="407902603339" />
</plugin>

<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" source="npm" spec="~1.4.5"/>

    <access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />

<platform name="android">
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />

</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Also added Content-Security-Policy meta tags in my HTML and pointed to domain where my API is located:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src *;
               style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
               script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

I am using build.phonegap.com online build service to build app. Please I really need help as I have done all the fixes which I could find but no success yet.

Comment: When they fail, can you check the network tab and see what HTTP code is returned?

Comment: Probably your content security policy.